# MongoDB: let different client reads from different replicas

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a heavy and large mongo table, which has a lot of reads. One of the read clients is an offline process which periodically scans a table aggressively. While other clients read the same table as online service. I'd like to separate them. What I'm thinking is to have a dedicate replica node for this offline client to read from, and then let the other clients read from the remaining replicas. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider marking one of the nodes as hidden member of the replica set. It will receive all the replicated writes from primary but won't receive any read traffic (from your online service if you use proper-replicaset-enabled connection string). Then from your offline client you can use connection string which targets the hidden member directly

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/